# How to prevent view from "flashing" at the end of a custom UIStoryboardSegue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, uistoryboardsegue

I have written a custom `UIStoryboardSegue` which I'm using to transition between various `UIViewControllers`. The animations work as desired, and much of the time the `UIStoryboardSegue` displays as I'd expected both in the simulator and on the device.

However, sometimes after the segue completes, I can see the old `UIViewController` **flash** for a fraction of a second after the `UIStoryboardSegue` completes. The result disrupts the smooth transition I am expecting. Unfortunately, I can't discern any pattern for this behaviour.

I've included a barebones version of the approach I'm using to manage the segue below. Is there a more reliable method to insure smooth transitions? Am I doing something wrong? Again, much of the time the segue looks just the way I want.

```
- (void)perform
{
    self.window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
    UIViewController *source = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *dest = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;

    [self.window insertSubview:dest.view.window belowSubview:source.view];

    self.segueLayer = [CALayer layer];
    // Create and add a number of other CALayers for displaying the segue,
    // adding them to the base segueLayer

    // Create and add CAAnimations for animating the CALayers
    // (code omitted for the sake of space)

    [self.window addSubview:dest.view];
    [self.window.layer addSublayer:self.segueLayer];

    [source.view removeFromSuperview];
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)animation finished:(BOOL)isFinished
{
    UIViewController *source = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *dest = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;

    if (isFinished)
    {
        // Remove and deallocate the CALayers previously created 
        [self.segueLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
        self.segueLayer = nil;
        self.window.rootViewController = dest;
    }
}
```

Comment: One suggestion I am trying: setting both the `removedOnCompletion = NO` and `fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards` for all my CAAnimation instances. Perhaps they are being reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So CAAnimations don't change the actual layer's values, but those of its associated `presentationLayer`. Setting the `fillMode` to `kCAFillModeForwards` ensures that the `presentationLayer`'s values don't revert after the animation completes. However, if the animation's `removedOnCompletion` property is set to `YES` (which it is by default), the layer's appearance can also revert to its pre-animation state.

Since the `animationDidStop:` callback likely gets invoked after any potential reversions, and because timings aren't exact, that would explain why you don't always see the reversion.

Comment: This account seems fairly convincing to me. I've tried setting `removedOnCompletion=NO` and also `fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards` and have not yet seen the problem manifest, I'm guessing this is a likely solution. I'm going to give it a bit more testing.

Comment: Well, I've run the new code over and over and and don't see any problems. Yay!